# Bing map to display a specific country instead of the whole world?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a specific country (UK to be exact) in the Bing map instead of the whole  world but I have no idea how to!

in my search, i found a blog question and the answer was that it is no possible but I don't think that is true because i have seen it done on many other sites etc..

so I would appreciate it if someone could advise on this issue.

my current code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var map = null, infobox, dataLayer;

          function GetMap() {
              // Initialize the map
              map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                         { credentials: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"




                          });

              dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
              map.entities.push(dataLayer);

              var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
              map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

              infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 20) });
              infoboxLayer.push(infobox);

              AddData();
          }

          function AddData() {
              var pin1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.555076763136704, 0.691519856452919));
              pin1.Title = "This is Pin 1";
              pin1.Description = "Pin 1 description";
              Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin1, 'click', displayInfobox);
              dataLayer.push(pin1);



          }

          function displayInfobox(e) {
              if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
                  infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
                  infobox.setOptions({ visible: true, title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description });
              }
          }  
   </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't explicitly tell it to zoom to the UK.

But you can create a rectangle (*bounding box*) and initialize the map using that rectangle as its bounds.

```
// create a rectangle around the UK (northwest / southeast corners) manually selected
var ukBox = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromCorners(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(58.909597, -11.449733), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(50.309499, 2.041477));

map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {
        credentials: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        bounds: ukBox // use the rectangle as the map bounds (for the initial render)
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nm1dx07L/

---

*Keep in mind that it will select the closest zoom level that will fit the rectangle. So it depends on the container dimensions.*